# print with GDI+ Graphics.DrawString produces garbage characters

Tags: c++, printing, gdi+

I'm using GDI+ Graphics.DrawString call to print a document with Chinese characters. All text are in Unicode (WCHAR). The problem is, on some computers (1% of all), all Chinese characters become garbage characters. It seems it tries to interpret the text in a difference code page.

1. I have found that only characters in regular style (FontStyleRegular) have problems. Characters in Bold style are OK.
2. I also tried to print to the "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" printer. The problem is the same. So it's not a problem with printer driver.
3. I have debugged the program and can assure the text parameter in the DrawString call is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by copying the font file from a good computer to the problematic one.